# View cache Data in quarkus dev-ui

Tags: caching, quarkus

Simple question, it is possible to visualize data cached from quarkus cache extension in the quarkus dev-ui ? I can visualiaze the count ouf elments but no the element cached. I found nothing about it in the documentation or i missed something...

Thanks
Guillaume

Comment: Sounds like a feature request :). Feel free to open an issue in our GH repo